# Problems installing everpad

Tags: lubuntu, everpad

I´ve got a problem concerning everpad.
I´m using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64 bit.
What I want to do is install everpad as it seems a good alternative to evernote.
Yet I have great difficulty in installing it. What I did is add the respective repository and then I tried to download it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install everpad
```

But my terminal says that the package "everpad" cannot be found.
Has anybody got any ideas what to do?

Many thanks in advance.

Greetings

Rosika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [that ppa stops at Vivid](https://launchpad.net/~nvbn-rm/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)(15.04), so it is not available for 16.04, the version that you are using.

You have to remove it from your system, otherwise it will break also your normal updates.

Comment: Hi dadexix86, thanks for your comment and the hint. O.K. that would explain why I cannot install everpad via ppa. I´m going to remove it right away. Alas, that doesn´t solve my original problem. Isn´t there another way to install everpad?

Comment: Sure it doesn't. Since your question is not about how to install it, I haven't addressed it. Flag this as solved and open another one specific to that problem. Please also note that Everpad was last developed 2 years ago, it will surprise me a lot that it will works. Indeed, have a look here https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues/492 on the official issue page of the project. It looks abandoned right now.

Comment: Hi dadexix86, thanks a lot for helping me. It seems like I have to look for an alternative to everpad. Thanks also for the link. Greetings.Rosika